# Rendering order of elements added to the DOM via jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have 2 exactly the same fixed-position `div` elements and I add them to the DOM via jQuery or JavaScript, which can I expected to appear on top?

For example:

```
div#a {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

div#b {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The reason for my question is during my testing I get the `div` I add first appearing on top. I would have expected the second `div` I added to appear on top.

**UPDATE:** Please note, I already understand z-index. Please consider my question with reference to both `div#a` and `div#b` having the exact same (default) z-index. Which would appear on top after adding to the DOM?

**My jQuery**

```
$( 'body' ).append( '<div id="a"></div>' );
$( 'body' ).append( '<div id="b"></div>' );
```

Comment: Can you provide us the code for adding the `divs` to the DOM?

Comment: @henrywright You only appear to be adding one div in that code.

Comment: look at [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: I know about z-index already, but thanks.

Comment: Interesting! Any chance you can throw together a fiddle that reproduces the issue? Here's a fiddle that appends two DIVs that seem to behave properly: http://jsfiddle.net/jpattishalljr/cc6dtx5n/

Comment: @JackPattishall Thanks for the jsfiddle - my thoughts on what should happen were exactly the same as the result you get in your code. There must be something funky with my code (I purposefully didn't supply everything to avoid confusion - I'm using a rather lengthy Plupload script). I think your comment confirms my thoughts and answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **jQuery** you can resolve it easy using the method `.prepend()` instead of `append()`. It is difficult to diagnostic because you have not posted your JS code but I think it will solve your issue.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="inner">Hello</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(".inner").prepend( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

**Result**

```
 <div class="inner">
    <p>Test</p>
    Hello
  </div>
```

It is working in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/YPPxMM).

Check out prepend() [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

Comment: Ah I think he was talking about z index stuff as answered by Fede

Comment: @Samer Mmm what I saw in the question comments is that he already knows about z-index and he also comment that he is appending the divs with the append() method. So I think my answer fit the question

Comment: Ah true I missed that part. When I read his initial question I just assumed the same what you said. I should read everything :)

Comment: @henrywright no, all divs are added dynamically. Look that I have to remove some styles to make it work. If you use fixed positions with the same top and left values the elements will be superimposed.

Answer (score 2):

You should use z-index property of css styles to set the stack order elements.
An element with greater z-index is always in front of an element with a lower z-index.
In your example:

```
div#a {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}

div#b {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In html hierarchy normally the later added html has higher z-index value than earlier element:

Look at this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/apmxzzpa/10/)

But since you're using jQuery with that and I think your first element is added later by jQuery and you're getting first element above.

So, to avoid confusion just apply z-index higher:

```
div#a {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}

div#b {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 2; /* 1 layer above */
}
```

Comment: I think that it is not the question purpose.